# SOLVED - sendRawTransaction (no) errors, valid tx, not found when scanned

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs-tx

I have a method that is supposed to create a transaction, send some wei and validate. When looking around I red that you can use infura.io. I also checked that you need to use raw transactions because infura doesn't handle it and it doesn't handle events anymore. But when trying to commit a tx it blocks at the data level. I am not sure if i am just calling my method wrong or if something is missing. I have tested with a method of type `view` and it returns true / false but transactions are not going through.
I am using `ethereumjs-tx` and `web3` **0.x.x (0.20.3)**

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/XXXXXXXX'));
var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
var contractInstance = contract.at('contract address');

// ERROR here / JSON RPC Error
    var data = contractInstance.myMethodInContract(100, {from: 'client address', value: payment_amount}); 

var rawTx = {  
      from: 'client address',
      to: 'contract address', 
      value: payment_amount, 
      data: data 
    }

    var privateKey = new Buffer('private key here', 'hex')

    var tx = new Tx(rawTx);
    tx.sign(privateKey);

    var serializedTx = tx.serialize();

    web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err, hash) {
        if (!err)
            console.log(hash); 
        else
            console.error(err);
    });
```

**Update**
Following the comments about adding `nonce` and fixing the `data` fields. I did so as follow.

```
var nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount('client adress') + 1;
var data = dataPass.contractInstance.getData(100);

var rawTx = {
    ...
    nonce: web3.toHex(nonce),
    ...
}
```

I got a transaction hash and it returns a tx hash but i have an `error transaction underpriced`, please note that i red the docs and checked it mutliple times therefore in my work / code i only included what i needed to skip what would be calculated by itself.

I have added the `gasPrice` and `gasLimit` to get rid of the **transaction underpriced** and **intristic gas too low** errors.

```
var gasPrice = web3.eth.gasPrice.toNumber() * 1.40
var rawTx = {
     ...
     gasPrice: web3.toHex(gasPrice),
     gasLimit: web3.toHex(100000),
     ....
}
```

I get a hash but i get nothing when i check the status on https://ropsten.etherscan.io i am told `Sorry, we are unable to locate this Transaction Hash`.

```
0x0a7605689071e...e
```

When reading around (not sure if true or not) the `chainId` for the rawTx was needed but to get the network Id you need web3 1.0 as i checked 0.20 doesn't have it implement (might be wrong) and even to hardcore the `chainId` doesn't seem good but for a started i ll get it but i am unable to find a way to get the `chainId` from transactions (viewing detail of any tx on the blockchain). When trying static numbers like in examples i saw i get a **Error: invalid sender**. 
Following this [Can not send eth on Ropsten using Infura node](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12054/can-not-send-eth-on-ropsten-using-infura-node/12263) I have added the proper chainId but i am not seeing the transaction on the https://ropsten.etherscan.io `Sorry, we are unable to locate this Transaction Hash`. 

I was adding  a `+ 1` to my `nonce` value which apparently made it not go through. To who wonders I added a `+ 1` because someone encountered an issue around where his tx wasn't going through and the proposed solution was the `+ 1` to `nonce` due to a potential pending tx already attempting to go through.

```
var nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount('client adress');
```

Comment: Try to add 'nonce' to your raw transaction. I'm not 100% sure about it, but it might help.

Comment: Also to calculate the `data` field you have to call `getData` in web3 v0.20, ie something like this `var data = contractInstance.myMethodInContract.getData(100);`

Comment: How exactly is this issue marked resolved?